# Unable to build Phoenix release

Tags: vagrant, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix application that has been running in the wild for 9 months or so, and as of a couple of days ago I was able to build a new release fine - now I get a `File.Error` that prevents building.

The last lines of the build output follow:

```
Generated phoenix_ecto app
==> [APP_NAME]
Check your digested files at "priv/static"
** (File.Error) could not remove files and directories recursively from     "/vagrant/app/_build/prod/lib/[APP_NAME]/priv": file already exists
    (elixir) lib/file.ex:919: File.rm_rf!/1
    (mix) lib/mix/project.ex:421: Mix.Project.symlink_or_copy/3
    (mix) lib/mix/project.ex:414: Mix.Project.build_structure/2
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:15: Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:296: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.ex:84: Mix.Tasks.Compile.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:296: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:58: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
```

Has anyone come across this?

Initially, I stopped the Phoenix server, and halted Vagrant. Then I started Vagrant again, ssh'd in, and built the release fine, so I figured it was a Vagrant thing.

Now it's started again, and the same 'workaround' doesn't work, so I guess I was just lucky the first time around. I've tried destroying the Vagrant box and rebuilding, but I still get the same error when building the release.

I'm stumped, and don't understand why this should have just started happening when, AFAIK, the build environment has not changed - and if it had, wouldn't rebuilding it with Vagrant fix it?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: I get the same error intermittently in my windows dev environment. If I refresh the error goes away. Check out this issue:https://github.com/hexpm/hex/issues/284